# Methods can only be called from within the same library

Tags: android, android-studio

Im using third party library.I Just want to replicate the same functionality.Im getting a warning saying that

**Method can only be called from within the same library**

Im still able to use the application perfectly without any issues.

What are the consequences of ignoring the warning from the complier and decides to go live with that?

Answer (score 0):

If your app always uses a fixed version of the library, there should be no issues whatsoever. It's just a linter warning, and can be safely ignored.

However, that API may change in future versions and break your application if your app uses those new versions.

So, the decision is yours, depending on how your app uses that library.